# All outgoing TCP requests begin to fail 30-40 minutes after starting my PC

Tags: networking, windows-10

This just started happening this morning, and has been happening all day. I have had to restart my system about a dozen times so far.

About 30-40 minutes after I start my PC, all outgoing TCP connections are dropped. Inbound connections appear to be unaffected. I can still receive messages on Slack, but I can't send messages or change to another channel (it will be blank if I try). Music streaming from Code Radio will continue to play indefinitely. I am also able to send pings to other devices on my network, to 8.8.8.8, and to google.ca with low latency and no packet loss. `curl google.ca` fails.

My PC is connected via ethernet. None of the other devices on the network have any connectivity issues. Only this machine is affected.

I tried running the "internet troubleshooter" and the "network troubleshooter" in Windows. Neither were at all helpful.

I tried running `netsh winsock reset`

I also tried `ipconfig /flushdns`

I also tried changing the dns in my ipv4 settings to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`

I even tried temporarily disabling my windows firewall, but even that didn't help

I tried unplugging the ethernet cable and plugging it back in

I tried resetting the router

The only way to restore my connection is to restart my computer, but it just happens again in another 40 minutes.

Until this morning, I haven't had any issues with my connection to the internet from this machine. It didn't start first thing in the morning, but a couple of hours after I started working. No Windows Updates were applied this morning or last night.

I'm on Windows 10 version 1903, Build 18362.836

Comment: First, add up in your question which the *full description of OS installed*, you get one with the cmd **winver**. Second, try to disable any *antivirus* installed on your machine too. Third, try to boot your OS in [**Recovery Mode**](https://www.techclassy.com/recovery-mode-windows/) and check out if the issue still occurs.

Comment: I've added the version & build number of the OS to the post.
I don't have any antivirus besides windows defender, and I already tried disabling that. I'm starting to suspect that the issue has something to do with the expo framework and the server it sets up to allow you to run the app you're working on on your phone wirelessly. It started happening when I started using it yesterday, and doesn't seem to happen unless I am using it.

Comment: Try scan your machine with the [Kaspersky Recue Disk](https://support.kaspersky.com/14226#block1) to drop the possibility of some malware to have infected it.